# django templates show the latest data first

Tags: django

I have to show the latest date of data in up side first, in my original code, it only show the oldest date of data in up side and list below to newer in down side

**django 2.2**

**modle.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

I think in views.py may be I have to make

**model = Article --> order_by('-date')**

something like that? how can I do ?

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Article


class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

in the form blow it will list the oldest date of data in up side and newer data in down side ,, what I wanna to do is the newest data in up side and older data in down side

**article_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Articles{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  {% for article in object_list %}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ article.title }}</span> &middot;
        <span class="text-muted">by {{ article.author }} | {{ article.date }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        {{ article.body }}
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
          <a href="{% url 'article_edit' article.pk %}">Edit</a> |
          <a href="{% url 'article_delete' article.pk %}">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

thank you for review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting `ordering` in `Meta` of your model:

To show in reverse order put **minus** `-` before field name.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

Comment: @chiao, Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Override the [**`get_context_data()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method

```
class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        if context_data['object_list']:
            context_data['object_list'] = context_data['object_list'].order_by('-date')
        return context_data
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way of achieving this is to use [**`ordering`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.ordering):

```
class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    ordering = ['-date']
```

I would recommend this approach beacuse in this way, the ordering is specific to that ListView, where if you change in models, it will be reflected everywhere(even in places where you don't need ordering by `-date`)